# unable to load Private Key from pem

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to generate a key to enable https on apache server under linux.

I took the certificat from godaddy that gave me .crt and .pem

I've tried to generate the key from the pem in many way:

*openssl pkey -in foo.pem -out foo.key*

*openssl rsa -in foo.pem -out foo.key*

Then I tried by an other way explain in some post I've found under stackoverflow

*openssl rsa -in key.pem -out keyout.pem*

and I always get this error message:

*unable to load Private Key*

*139675415795008:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY*

Someone can explain to me what is my mistake and how to resolve it ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You used your private key to sign the CSR for godaddy.  You don't send them the private key or it would not be private.  The private key is not  in the certificate, which is public.  https://www.godaddy.com/help/generate-a-csr-certificate-signing-request-5343

Comment: Godaddy has generated an SSL DV certificate for my DNS name. I don't really understand. I think I need to generate my own private key and not convert it from the PEM? Is it correct?

Comment: The private key must be the one used to generate the certificate or it won't match.

Comment: https://www.godaddy.com/help/wheres-my-private-key-32300

Comment: If I understand correctly I have to generate it, because Godaddy doesn't give it to you when they create the certificate. By using this command ``sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa`` or ``ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096``. is it correct?